# Error handling - 500 from API logs a cryptic error in angular5

Tags: angular, error-handling

I'm using Angular5.  I have what I think is a simple setup.  I have a component injected with a SignupService which calls an API.  This all works fine in the event that nothing goes wrong.  But if the remote server returns an error (specifically a 500 is what I'm dealing with right now but any error should be similar) I'd like to handle it appropriately on the client side.  Unfortunately I keep getting this unhelpful error in the catch handler:

> "You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide
>   an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable."

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental, because my error handling code looks similar to other code examples I've seen on the web.   Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

excerpt from signup.service.ts

```
public signup(value: SignupForm): Observable<TokenResponse | any> {
    return this.http.post<TokenResponse>(
      `${environment.AUTHENTICATION_API}/p/signup`,
      value,
      this.httpOptions
    )
  }
```

excerpt from signup.component.ts:

```
public signup(value: SignupForm): void {
    if (this.myForm.valid && !this.submitted) {
      this.submitted = true;
      // submit to API
      this.service.signup(value)
        .first()
        .finally(() => {
          this.submitted = false;
        })
        .subscribe(data => {
          // handle session/token stuff, this works fine.
        }, e => {
          console.log('got error', e);
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is your client origin and api origin ? if they are on different origins you should use proxy to handle your errors

Comment: It's just localhost for now.  Like I said, this works fine if the server doesn't throw an error.  Even if they weren't, I don't need a proxy server to handle cors requests when I allow the origin domain.

Comment: What is your server and client ports ?

Answer (score 0):

OK as I expected this ended up being a silly thing, I have an HTTP interceptor set up and in the event of a 500 response I was not properly returning Observable.throw(err) back to the caller.  Adding that made everything work.